# XLib: 'Soft-Closing' a window

Tags: c, window, xlib

I know, that I can 'close' an X11 Window by calling:

```
XDestroyWindow(display, id);
```

The problem is, this destroyes the window immediately. On the other hand, if i click the close button (x in the title bar) the app can show something like "Do you really want to exit?".

So how can I emulate this type of window closing?

---

Background:
I am closing windows from other applications, not my own

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
XEvent event;
event.xclient.type = ClientMessage;
event.xclient.window = id;
event.xclient.message_type = XInternAtom(d, "WM_PROTOCOLS", TRUE);
event.xclient.format = 32;
event.xclient.data.l[0] = XInternAtom(d, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", FALSE);
event.xclient.data.l[1] = CurrentTime;
XSendEvent(d, id, False, NoEventMask, &event);
```

Where `d` is the display handle and `id` is the window ID.

### CREDIT: https://john.nachtimwald.com/2009/11/08/sending-wm_delete_window-client-messages/

Answer (score 1):

It can be the same as 
[stackoverflow.com/questions/1157364/intercept-wm-delete-window-on-x11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157364/intercept-wm-delete-window-on-x11)

Comment: that is not directly what I need, but maybe the first answer is quite helpfull, thanks anyways!